# Can someone identify these drop tanks?

Tags: fuel, feature-identification

I was wondering if anyone can help me identify either of these drop tanks?  The one in front in the top photo measures about 11' long.

[image: aircraft fuel drop tank]  [image: aircraft fuel drop tank]

(Source of second photo-- [this related ASE question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77325/fuel-drop-tank-identification-needed))

Comment: Do you know where it was found? That would be useful.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going with tip tank for a Lockheed P-80 Shooting Star.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The teardrop tank was already answered for, so I’ll just field the second half. The blue tank looks like one produced by Firestone (same outline, same seam, same filler and even similar appearing attachment points) - shown here (source https://usautoindustryworldwartwo.com/images/Firestone/maps-droptanks-107w-1.jpg) [image: Firestone drop tank]

Addendum - these appear to have been used on P-51s per this link (I won’t embed the images being unsure of the usage rights):

http://www.sim-outhouse.com/sohforums/showthread.php/67664-quot-FF-902-quot/page2?p=718648&viewfull=1#post718648

Comment: here's a public domain photo: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:194th_Fighter_Squadron_-_North_American_F-51D-30-NA_Mustang_44-74825_Treasure_Island.jpg